# Audio Hijack alternative?

Tags: audio

I have owned this program for 16 years but they keep demanding money for new versions that have "improvements" of absolutely no use to me and I think probably not to most people. It seems a bit of a money grab and they have just done it again with the Ventura update.

All I want is to record application audio. Is there anything free available or less likely to turn into expensive bloatware?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140770/discussion-on-question-by-appalling-audio-hijack-alternative).

Answer (score 0):

Soundflower can redirect the Mac input/output audio. Once installed, using the Sound Network Preference, the audio output can be directed to SoundFlower.

https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower

Additional info: https://soundflower.en.softonic.com/mac

QuickTime Player can record audio from a choice of input sources, so after starting the audio recording, the SoundFlower channel can be selected as input.

The disadvantage is that the audio is not hearable from the regular speakers.

I know this works under Mojave, I don't know about newer OS versions. A newer option (I haven't tested) is called Loopback.

https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/

---

Another option is [BlackHole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) instead of Soundflower. I have no experience with that though.